# iOS: Autoresize components horizontally in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoresizingmask, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains a selection of different components. Depending whether the device is in landscape or portrait mode some of the components may run over the edges horizontally. What I want to achieve is a setup where the components autoresize horizontally, but stay the same vertically (i.e. no more need to scroll horizontally).

I have fixed the `UIScrollView` so that they can only scroll veertically. The problem is that now the content inside the scroll view is not being resized in the horizontal direction (as expected I guess).

I have had a look around online and tried out a few solutions, however I cannot find a way to make the components inside the `UIScrollView` to autoresize in the horizontal, but stay the same in the vertical.

Please could anyone advise whether this is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//for the scrollView set the below property.
[scrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
//then for every subView of your scrollView set the below property.
[subView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[scrollview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[subview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

or follow this link for your help

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html